# If in Flutter I await openDatabase(), am I awaiting onCreate and onUpgrade too?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Package Sqflite, if I await an openDatabase() operation, can I be sure I will wait for the completion of onCreate and onUpgrade function too?
Or I wait just for openDatabase() but onCreate and onUpgrade will be executed (if necessary, obviously) as async in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. openDatabase will only complete once onCreate (when the database is created) or onUpgrade (when the version is upgraded) are completed. You can verify that by adding some logs/print in onCreate and onUpgrade and after openDatabase.